# mongoose query to get all distinct documents from mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how can i get all distinct documents from mongodb collection using mongoose query? when I use distinct with find query I'm getting array of distinct elements of the given field.

```
MyModel.find().distinct('_id', function(error, ids) {
// ids is an array of all ObjectIds
});
```

Comment: Distinct of what fields (whole document)? You can try using Aggregation''s [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#retrieve-distinct-values).

Comment: I think so - try the link in my previous comment. Also, search for grouping by multiple fields.

Comment: yes. whole document.is it possible to use Aggregation''s $group? For example, get distinct customer details from order collection.